# Golang mongo driver performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, go

I have written some code for testing mongodb. 
But its speed is so bad.
What is wrong with is?

```golang
func mgoSpeedTest(N int) int64 {
    session, err := mgo.Dial(MongoHost)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        sessionCopy := session.Copy()
        c := session.DB(MongoDB).C(MongoCol)
        _, err = c.Find(bson.M{"id": 1}).Count()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        sessionCopy.Close()
    }
    t := time.Now()
    elapsed := t.Sub(start)
    return elapsed.Milliseconds()
}

func main() {
    // speed test
    N := 1000
    ms = mgoSpeedTest(N)
    println(fmt.Sprintf("mgo: %d", ms))
}
```

Answer ~~ 3500ms
I tried to use mongo-client but speed is the same ~3700-3800

Comment: You execute 1 thousand queries, averaging 3.5 ms (this includes network transfer back and forth, database execution, result handling, session copying and closing). **What is considered good?** Given what's happening under the hood, I don't think it's bad. Use the same session if you want better performance.

Comment: I also tried insert 1000 documents to localhost database.
1000 inserts = 36 seconds.
But in official speed performance speed is the difference

Comment: I would also execute an `mgo.Dial()` call before starting the timer, to make sure your session is ready.

Comment: And you preclude the possibility that it is your code behaving badly? I would not. Disclose the code and we can find out where the problem is. Hint: If that was the general experience, nobody would use the mongo driver. Not even MongoDB Inc. And all their tools (`mongodump` etc) are written in Go.

Comment: Furthermore, you a looking up `id` (not `_id`, mind you). That basically means a [collection scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667173/what-is-a-collection-scan-in-mongodb) is happening. Gist: MongoDB needs to open each and every document, read it, compare the value of the field `id` with 1. Btw, your code does not even compile - I have the feeling that you withhold information either accidentally or intentionally. If code is missing, that precludes us from helping you properly.

Answer (score 4):

> **Important**
>
> Much to my dismay, I cannot suggest to use mgo any more, since it seems to be [no longer maintained as of the time of this writing](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo/issues/371#issuecomment-527873696).

I was curious and compiled a little benchmark of my own. It uses a single instance MongoDB via docker:

```sh
$ docker run -d --name mongobench -p 27017:27017 mongo
731e5f57d677718244c2304a992abd44a5a4bbad6f1fd8e5a23e53b3c4f9ada4
```

> Note: The hash you get will be different.

As per the benchmark, it is twofold: simple insert and bulk inserts. Bulk inserts are the preferred way of dealing with mass insertions.

It tests both the mgo driver and the mongo-go-driver:

```golang
package mongobench

// Use
//  docker run -d --name mongobench -p 27017:27017 mongo
// to create a suitable test instance and access it via
//  docker exec -it mongobench mongo

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "testing"

    "github.com/globalsign/mgo"
    "github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type Data struct {
    ID      primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Counter int
}

const DefaultHost = "localhost:27017"
const DefaultDB = "test"
const DefaultCollection = "bench"

var sess *mgo.Session
var client *mongo.Client

func init() {
    var err error

    sess, err = mgo.Dial(DefaultHost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("setting up session: %s", err)
    }

    client, err = mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://" + DefaultHost))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("setting up client: %s", err)
    }

    if err = client.Connect(context.Background()); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("connecting with client: %s", err)
    }
}
func BenchmarkMgoInsert(b *testing.B) {

    c := sess.DB(DefaultDB).C("simple")
    if _, err := c.RemoveAll(bson.M{}); err != nil {
        b.Logf("cleaning collection 'simple': %s", err)
        b.FailNow()
    }

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if err := c.Insert(&Data{ID: bson.NewObjectId(), Counter: i}); err != nil {
            b.Logf("error inserting: %s", err)
            b.FailNow()
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkMgoBulk(b *testing.B) {
    c := sess.DB(DefaultDB).C("bulk")
    if _, err := c.RemoveAll(bson.M{}); err != nil {
        b.Logf("cleaning collection 'simple': %s", err)
        b.FailNow()
    }

    b.ResetTimer()

    bulk := c.Bulk()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bulk.Insert(&Data{ID: bson.NewObjectId(), Counter: i})
    }

    if _, err := bulk.Run(); err != nil {
        b.Logf("executing bulk: %s", err)
        b.FailNow()
    }
}

func BenchmarkMongoInsert(b *testing.B) {
    c := client.Database(DefaultDB).Collection("mongosimple")
    if _, err := c.DeleteMany(context.Background(), bson.M{}); err != nil {
        b.Logf("cleaning collection 'mongosimple': %s", err)
        b.FailNow()
    }

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        c.InsertOne(context.Background(), &Data{ID: bson.NewObjectId(), Counter: i})
    }
}

func BenchmarkMongoBulk(b *testing.B) {

    c := client.Database(DefaultDB).Collection("mongobulk")
    if _, err := c.DeleteMany(context.Background(), bson.M{}); err != nil {
        b.Logf("cleaning collection 'mongosimple': %s", err)
        b.FailNow()
    }

    d := make([]mongo.WriteModel, b.N)

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        d[i] = mongo.NewInsertOneModel().SetDocument(Data{ID: bson.NewObjectId(), Counter: i})
    }

    if _, err := c.BulkWrite(context.Background(), d); err != nil {
        b.Logf("inserting bulk: %s", err)
        b.FailNow()
    }

}
```

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/mwmahlberg/so-mongobench
BenchmarkMgoInsert-4            1164       1100919 ns/op        1501 B/op         44 allocs/op
BenchmarkMgoBulk-4            201560          6512 ns/op         258 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkMongoInsert-4          1171       1019140 ns/op        3642 B/op         66 allocs/op
BenchmarkMongoBulk-4          181040          7251 ns/op        1151 B/op         15 allocs/op
```

What we can see is that both drivers are orders of magnitude faster than what you describe, hence it is safe to assume that it is not the driver causing the delays.

Comment: where are you defining Data{}  ?

Comment: @ScottStensland To be fair, I did not, since I thought it would be too obvious. Will add it.